# R if else statements, skipping the if and just doing the else

Tags: r, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

The following R code is part of a bigger function, and it keeps skipping the if statements and just doing the else statement at the end. Any suggestions? thanks

```
if(solv==0){
theta<-pi/2
} else if(solv==1){
theta<-0
}  else if(solv==-1) {
theta<-pi
}  else{
comb<-top/bottom

theta<-acos(comb)}
```

Comment: Too few information. Try `print(solv)` before your `if` statement?

Comment: What is letting you know that it is not working?  Can you share that specific piece of information.  I would put `dput(solve)` right before your if statement

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal?lq=1. Try `if (isTRUE(all.equal(solve, 0)))` etc.

Comment: sorry that I didn't put more information, but the '(isTRUE(all.equal(solv, 0)))' did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The important question is, **is `solve` an integer?**

If not, then as @GSee alludes to in the comments to your question, the bug in your code is related to [floating point errors](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)

Try the following instead

```
# Set whichever tolerance is acceptable to you
tol <- 1e-16

if(isTRUE(all.equal(solv, 0, tolerance=tol))){
theta<-pi/2
} else if(isTRUE(all.equal(solv, 1, tolerance=tol))){
theta<-0
}  else if(isTRUE(all.equal(solv, -1, tolerance=tol))) {
theta<-pi
}  else{
comb<-top/bottom

theta<-acos(comb)}
```